# Can I get location access without generating the default popup in iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, gps

I am working on an app that requires location access. I created a view controller asking the user to allow or not with 2 buttons. But when I click the allow button, device is generating it's own popup asking the user for location access. Can I avoid the popup and just add the functionality of allow in popup into my code for the allow button in my app itself?

Comment: You can not avoid permission for location access which is displayed by the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot avoid system popup. As per apple

> Always request authorization at the point where you actually plan to
>   use location services to perform a task. Requesting authorization may
>   display an alert to the user. If it is not clear to the user that your
>   app is using location services for a useful purpose, the user may deny
>   your request to use those services.

Also, It is safe to start location services before the authorization status of your app is determined. Although you can start location services, those services do not deliver any data until the authorization status changes to `authorizedAlways` or `authorizedWhenInUse`. To be notified when the authorization status changes, implement the `locationManager(_:didChangeAuthorization:)` method in your location manager delegate.

[Sorce](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager)

Comment: I know that this is not possible, because I have done my research on it. I checked everywhere and found that apple puts it's users in front of the developers regarding this issue. I posted this question just to get some proof to show my project manager who was not believing me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, Not possible in Apple device yet.